# Move database outside App_Data folder

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a website using VS2010 + SQL Server 2008 R2.

My development website has its DB located in App_Data, however the production DB is located outside the project.

When I upload the project, I don't want to upload a redundant DB, so plan to move the DB outside. The issue is that I'm no SQL expert - is there an easy way to get this set up externally to the project?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a connectionstring to the MS SQL Server database given in the config file in your ASP .NET application. Then you can change the connection string when you deploy your application in the web.config to point at any database as you wish.

Here you can read more on connectionstrings: http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/